# Rails referral model with self referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to create a Referral program on a Rails app and I struggle with the relationships.

My Referral model is pretty simple : `godfather_id`, `godson_id`, `state`
Both godfather and godson ids references an User, which can have many godsons but only one godfather.

```rb
class Referral < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :godson, class_name: 'User'
end
```

The issue comes in my User model. I wan't to be able to do `user.godsons` to get an array of *godsons* Users and `user.godfather` to get the *godfather* User.

I tried a few things and I think those two where the closest to what I need to do (User model simplified for the example).

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :referrals
  has_many :godson, -> { where(godfather_id: id) }, through: :referrals
  has_one :godfather, -> { where(godson_id: id) }, through: :referrals
end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :godson_relations, class_name: 'Referral', foreign_key: 'godson_id'
  has_many :godsons, through: :godson_relations
  has_one :godfather_relation, class_name: 'Referral', foreign_key: 'godfather_id'
  has_one :godfather, through: :godfather_relations
end
```

I'm really unsure about how to materialize this relationship, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an actual self-referential assocation you would just add a column on the users table that points back to the same table:

```
class AddGodfatherToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]                                                                                                                                       
  def change                                                                                                                                                                                      
    add_reference :users, :godfather, null: true, 
                                      foreign_key: { to_table: :users }                                                                                                                           
  end                                                                                                                                                                                        end
```

```
class User
  belongs_to :god_father,
    class_name: 'User',
    optional: true,
    inverse_of: :god_children
  has_many :god_children,
    class_name: 'User',
    foreign_key: :god_father_id
    inverse_of: :god_father
end
```

If you must store Referalls as a separate table you were kind of on the right track but you got the foreign keys backwards:

```
class Referral < ApplicationRecord
  # you better be explicit here or its going to get extremely confusing
  belongs_to :godfather, class_name: 'User' 
  belongs_to :godson, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :referrals_as_godfather, 
    class_name: 'Referral', foreign_key: 'godfather_id'
  has_one :referral_as_godson, 
    class_name: 'Referral', 
    foreign_key: 'godfather_id'
  has_many :godsons, through: :referrals_as_godfather
  has_one :godfather, through: :referral_as_godson
end
```

It should be noted that `has_one` in no way guarentees that a user can have only one referral (and thus one godfather). It just adds a LIMIT 1 to the query. You would have to enforce that with a uniqueness constraint and validations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I do have to create a separate table because I'll need to handle transitions, notifications, rewards etc.  However, following your advice, I have an issue when trying to get `user.godfather`.

I thought the problem came from the `:referral_as_godson` foreign_key but when trying with `godson_id` instead of `godfather_id` I have the same error `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError`.

Comment: Oops. It should have been `has_one :referral_as_godson, class_name: 'Referral', foreign_key: 'godson_id'`.

Comment: I thought so yeah, I managed to make it work, the only thing that wasn't right was the bigint type missing in the migration for the ids. Thanks!